# Setting environment variable and checking value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I need to set an environment variable and later check if it is set and if so, execute a block of code inside my htaccess.  I already tried it using SetEnvIfNoCase and later with `<If>` but the environment variable created didnt look to be available to the `<If>` statement.

```
SetEnvIf Query_string ".*" VARIABLE=HI

<If "%{ENV:VARIABLE} == 'HI'">

    #DO SOMETHING HERE

</If>
```

The "DO SOMETHING HERE" never gets executed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an env var that way for a query string. You have to use mod_rewrite to set it based on query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
#match any query string and set a variable.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=QUERY_ENV:HI]
```

Then you have to use the [reqenv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions) function to look it up.

```
<If "reqenv('QUERY_ENV') =~ /HI/">

    #DO SOMETHING HERE

</If>
```

Comment: For some reason when using "<if>" Apache does not see the variable set using rewriteRule... Any other idea?